# Header value not used as object key

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

[image]

I'm working with node , puppeteer and cheerio, and I'd like to scrape the header and footer info of the table

I have the following :

```
const data = await page.content(); // get all page html
const $ = cheerio.load(data);

const head = $('#tblAcctBal > thead > tr');
const foot = $('#tblAcctBal > tfoot > tr');
const h = $(head).find('th');
const f = $(foot).find('th');
for (let i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
  const hElement = $(h[i]).text();
  const fElement = $(f[i]).text();
  myArr.push({hElement: fElement });
}
  console.log(myArr);
```

[image]

I can confirm from stepping through the code that the appropriate header column and footer column text is in both hElement, fElement.

However, when I look at the output of the array I see:

```
0:
{hElement: ''}
1:
{hElement: ''}
2:
{hElement: ''}
3:
{hElement: ''}
4:
{hElement: ''}
5:
{hElement: '$0.00'}
6:
{hElement: '$0.00'}
7:
{hElement: '$0.00'}
8:
{hElement: '$0.00'}
9:
{hElement: '$0.00'}
```

In the loop, I see the correct header value , but hElement shows up in the array as the key for all the objects - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 myArr.push({hElement: fElement });
```

Needs to be this:

```
 myArr.push({[hElement]: fElement });
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but why do you have to do that?

Comment: check this link about javascript computed properties: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-computed-property/